# Is this is the correct and full list of authentications methods to authenticate Azure services?

Tags: java, azure, authentication, service

I use the Azure SDK to build my project in Java. And I need to authenticate to some Azure services below:

1. File Storage
2. Queue Storage
3. Service Bus Queue
4. Service Bus Topic
5. Data Lake
6. Data Lake Gen 2
7. Blob Storage
8. Event Hub

I found a short documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.azure.authenticate?view=azure-java-legacy and it just mentions about 4 authenticate() methods. But it does not confirm what service they are used for. And I am still concerned if they are all able to use for the above services?

Currently, I want to know a list of auth methods in Azure SDK for each service as I mentioned above.

Please advise me and thanks so much!

Comment: I really struggle to understand what you really want to know, but I guess a good first place to read for you is the Identity SDK library for java https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the same auth method for all the services you list?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Exactly, I want to have a list of auth methods for each service as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in Azure, different services use different auth methods, they can be roughly divided into two categories(not all the services).

1. Use basic auth, some services will provide something like a connection string, account name and key, then you can use them to access the service easily.
2. Use Azure AD auth, some services support to use Azure AD auth, you need to use a user account/service principal, give the [RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) at the resource scope you want to access, then use the OAuth flows e.g. [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the token, then use the token to access the Azure REST API for the specific service. In this way, usually there will be SDK for you, so you don't need to do the above manually.

For the services you list, some use one of them, and some can use both of them.

1.File Storage - It uses the account name and key to auth, you need to use them to build the client, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=java).

2.Queue Storage - It also uses the account name and key to auth, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-java-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=java).

3&4. Service Bus Queue & Topic - They can use [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-preview#create-service-bus-clients-using-a-connection-string) or [azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-preview#create-a-service-bus-client-using-microsoft-identity-platform-formerly-azure-active-directory) to auth, create the [client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-preview#service-bus-clients), then you can access queue and topic.

5.Data Lake - It uses azure ad [auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk#authentication), it provides two scenarios, you can choose them depending on your requirement, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk).

6.Data Lake Gen 2 - It uses [account name and key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#connect-by-using-an-account-key), or [azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#connect-by-using-azure-active-directory-azure-ad) to auth, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java).

7.Blob Storage - It uses the connection string to auth, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell).

8.Event Hub - It uses the connection string to auth, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send).

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks, @joy. One more question, How about OAuth2? Can we use it to authenticate those Azure services?

Comment: @NoName Yes, the services that use azure ad to auth essentially use azure ad OAuth 2.0 flows to auth, not all the services, because some of them don't support that.

Comment: Thanks, Joy. I accepted your answer to my question.